# Kusto: flag array elements

Tags: azure-data-explorer

I have a kusto array with hundred of element. For each of them I want to check if the value is below or above a threshold and set a flag value. I want the flag to be store in another array. Is there any function to do that? I could not find any.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There are series comparison functions in KQL which could be used on arrays with numeric elements, for example checking for elements **greater** than some threshold:

```
print s1 = dynamic([1,2,4])
| extend s1_greater_than_2 = series_greater(s1, 2)

+---------+--------------------+
|  s1     |  s1_greater_than_2 |
+---------+--------------------+
| [1,2,4] | [false,false,true] |
+---------+--------------------+
```